# Can I share a link for downloading a specific file in my public GitHub repository?

Tags: version-control, github, bitbucket.org

Just like the question says... I am looking for a free version control system that allows me to share individual scripts out of a larger project.

So, can GitHub or BitBucket do something like this? Is it possible to have a public repository with many scripts, and send someone a link for downloading an individual script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In GitHub, if you view a file, there is a link to the `raw`-version of the file.

It should look like this:

```
https://github.com/user/repository/raw/branch/filename
```

When you replace the blankets, with the real filename etc, than you can download it with `curl` or `wget`. 
So you could send this link to share this file. But it won't have version-control features from git etc.

Comment: Oh man, that is just perfect, I want to give you extra points.

Comment: You are welcome. Nice that it works.

Comment: Now, is there a way to request an _earlier_ version of the file?

Comment: You can use the commit ID to get an earlier version `https://github.com/user/repository/raw/{commitID}/filename`

Comment: Note that you should copy the *link* that "Raw" points to rather than the resulting page. It will be of the format `https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/raw/{branch}/{path}`. If you click the link, it will redirect you to a page which requires a token and the path is slightly different: `https://raw.github.com/{user}/{repo}/raw/{branch}/{path}?token={token}`. Giving it the wrong token will result in a "Not Found" page, thus you should use the first URL.